# How to get started with an obstacle avoidance robot using sharp IR sensors?

Tags: ros, arduino, obstacle-avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to design an obstacle avoiding robot using IR sensors and arduibo, can anyone guide me how to get started with programming in ROS? I have already completed my work with rosserial-arduino. I want to know how to make decisions in ROS depending upon the data coming from sensors, and on basis of those decisions I want to control my motors.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150256/how-to-get-started-with-an-obstacle-avoidance-robot-using-sharp-ir-sensors?/) by [Abdul_Manan](https://answers.ros.org/users/14566/abdul_manan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just use IR sensors and an Arduino, you´ll probably be fine without using ROS for your system. If you want to exchange data with a ROS system you can directly follow the rosserial arduino tutorials, like the [Hello World tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World) that shows how to publish from Arduino to the ROS network. If you have any specific questions regarding this, you should edit your question with more details on your problem.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdul_Manan](https://answers.ros.org/users/14566/abdul_manan/) on 2014-04-09**:
Well I am doing this as a university project so I have to use ROS on my system, so if you can guide me through this? after completing this obstacle avoiding task, i want to implement SLAM through ROS.
basically I want to know how i can make decisions on ROS depending upon the data coming from sensors via arduino.???